# Access NancyContext outside Module

Tags: nancy

I have a "service" class that does certain logic outside of my Nancy Modules. The service class is registered with the container so that I may access an instances in my modules through contructor injection. If my class depends on the NanyContext, how can I access it from outside a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NancyContext` is created per request, so taking a dependency on it only makes sense if the scope of your service is no longer than a request. Otherwise you will have to pass in `NancyContext` with the method calls you make to your service.

If the service has request scope you could create and register it in the `ConfigureRequestContainer` of the `Bootstrapper`:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
    {
         var service = new Service(context);
         container.Register(service);
         base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use this `container.Register(context);`?

Comment: But it seems I cannot not. Getting an error. Finally, I wrap `NancyContext` to `MyContext` then expose some helper function from `MyContext`. That is good for me. Thanks!